# Does toLocaleTimeString in Node.js support the hour12 option?

Tags: node.js, date

I can't seem to get hour12 time working in node.js, however in the browser (Chrome) it's working just fine.

**Node.js in terminal**

```
var date = new Date();
var d12 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12:true});
var d24 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12:false});
console.log(d12) // output 13:43:38 
console.log(d24) // output 13:43:38
```

Both yeild the same result:
13:43:38

**Update**
Adding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u4rcavb/1/) to prove it works in browser

Could someone point me to the docs that explain why,  or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just you. I tried running the same chunk in Node.js and couldn't get a way to print it in 12 hour format easily.

After doing some Googling, it seems like Moment.js is a popular tool for manipulating and displaying time and days. If you need to manipulate a lot of time/dates, it may be worth checking out, [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/).

```
// with Moment
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().format('hh:mm'));
```

Otherwise,

```
// just one of many ways to do it in Javascript
function hour12 (hour) {
  var mod = hour % 12;

  if (mod < 10) {
    return '0'.concat(mod);
  } else {
    return mod;
  }
}

console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/[\d]+/, hour12(date.getHours())));
```

**EDIT** I answered this question late at night, and realized I sort of missed the mark on addressing the question.

Since Node.js is based off Chrome's v8 JavaScript engine, I started poking around in the source code. I can't see a place where it takes into account arguments passed to it.

Code is [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/src/date.js), `toLocaleTimeString` is line 324. In comparison, I looked around Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine and it at a glance, it seems to account for this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy.

Comment: Added a more appropriate answer for the question asked.

Comment: I'll give you the points for the extra work.  You're confirming that I'm not actually doing anything wrong, and V8 just doesn't follow the spec. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toLocaleDateString** and **toLocaleTimeString** to format times and dates. The first parameter passed to these methods is a locale value, such as "en-us". The second parameter, where present, specifies formatting options, such as the long form for the weekday.

I've used Chrome and works well.

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 3, 7, 14, 30, 0));
var options = {
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
    day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
};

document.write(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx